# cakephp query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I wonder if there is a better way to achieve this:

```
$rights = $this->User->Role->Right->query(
    "SELECT ri.*
    FROM rights AS ri 
    LEFT JOIN roles_rights AS rr ON rr.right_id = ri.id 
    LEFT JOIN users_roles AS ur ON ur.role_id = rr.role_id
    WHERE ur.user_id = " . Sanitize::clean($user['User']['id']));
```

I hope, that there is a better way to get all rights for a specific user.

I would like to access the rights via the $this->User->... Is this possible?

A user has one or more roles and a role has one or more rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flipping it over:

```
$rights = $this->User->Role->Right->query(
  SELECT ri.* 
  FROM users_roles AS ur
  INNER JOIN roles_rights AS rr ON rr.role_id = ur.role_id
  INNER JOIN rights ri ON ri.id = rr.right_id
  WHERE ur.user_id = Sanitize::clean($user['User']['id']));
```

Comment: where is the benefit? I would like to access the rights via the model. Can't I get an instance of User and do something like that: `$rights = $User->Role->Right->find('list');` ?

Comment: ok :) But the impact of the order of the JOIN statements isn't too big, is it?

Comment: With your aproach your joining all rights, all roles and all users (even when there are no relation because of the left join) and then you filter out the user you want..

With my aproach you just select the user you want and only join that row..

But then again, the database server might be smart and optimize the query so the result is basically the same..

In which case you are left only with a easier to read query.. (Inner join is always easier the left joins..)

Comment: ok thanks, I will use your query as long as I can't find a cakephp way of doing that